# Adding a number to a date in excel (with an average and st dev)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of dates. They're dummy data for sign up dates.

I want to add another list that is dummy data for first usage dates.

To make the dates, I used this -

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2017,1,1),DATE(2017,6,30))
```

To make the first usages dates, I'm trying this -

```
=C6+RANDBETWEEN(0,100)
```

But, I don't want to just add a random number. I want to add a number from a normal distribution with a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 30 (without going into negatives). Is that possible?

Comment: The short answer is 'no' because if you excluded the negative values from a generated normal distribution with a mean of 10 and SD of 30, it wouldn't be a normal distribution any more.

Answer (score 0):

The following will generate a random number in normal distribution with a mean of 10 and deviation of 30:

```
= NORM.INV(RAND(),10,30)
```

The easiest way I can think of to exclude negative values is to just take the absolute value of this.

```
= ABS(NORM.INV(RAND(),10,30))
```

But, as already noted, if you exclude negative numbers (no matter how you decide to exclude them), then it isn't really a normal distribution anymore.

**EDIT:**

Another way to exclude negative numbers is the following:

Since `NORM.INV(0.37,10,30)` returns a value just above 0, you can use this knowledge to change the formula to only allow random values between 0.37 and 1 to be generated:

```
= NORM.INV(0.63*RAND()+0.37,10,30)
```

However, again I must point out this isn't a true normal distribution.